# Trying to resize an array by -1

Tags: c++, arrays, resize

I'm trying to resize an array I have in an other header. I need to take the current array and make it one smaller. This is the code I have in my header handling resizing:

```
void resize(const unsigned int & newCap = 0) {
        // first, copy over old array into temp location
        Type* newArray = new Type[Capacity];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Capacity; i++)
            newArray[i] = array[i];

        // Remove the old array, create with new capacity, copy over values
        delete[] array;
        if (newCap == 0)
            array = new Type[Capacity * 2];
        else if (newCap > Capacity)
            array = new Type[newCap];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < newCap; i++) array[i] = newArray[i];

        // set the capacity
        if (newCap == 0)
            Capacity = Capacity * 2;
        else
            Capacity = newCap;

        delete[] newArray;
    }
```

In the other header I'm simply sending it

```
array.resize(array.size() - 1);
```

I'm hoping to get an output where if I had an array with {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, my end goal would be to have an array with {1, 2, 3, 4}. I'm getting all sort of errors, not just one consistently error.

I'm sorry if my formatting isn't the best, I'm still learning.

Comment: What is Capacity?

Comment: Sorry, Capacity is how much my array can hold. The header handling my resizing is similar to how a vector works. I wanted to learn how they work so I just don't rely on them.

Comment: Also you do not need to delete both the newArray that you made and the array that you had.

Comment: @user4581301 could you clarify a little more? I'm not sure if I follow.

Comment: @boyanhristov96 I thought I had to delete array before I could give it a new size. Also I know I don't need to delete newArray, however from what I've heard, it's bad practices to not delete when calling new.

Comment: What is `array`? I have a feeling you're not using it right.

Comment: You will have to delete array but not the newArray. You will also need to have a delete[] array in the destructor of the class.

Comment: @Chipster array in my resizing header is an int Type*. I included my resizing header in my other header so that array is a resizing-header int Type array.

Comment: @boyanhristov96 Thank you for pointing this out, I do currently do this though

Comment: No problem. Someone just gave the answer

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. I think you have duplicate names, and that's what threw me. `array` is treated like a pointer inside `resize()`, but like an object outside of it. Surely you must have 2 things names `array`, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether the capacity gets larger or smaller the logic looks like:

1. Allocate new array of the desired size
2. Copy items from array into new array until there are no mere items in array or new array is full.
3. Free array.
4. Point array at new array.

In code:

```
void resize(unsigned int newCap) // no need for reference here. 
                                 // No reference, no need for const
{
    if (newCap == 0)
    {
         newCap = Capacity * 2;
    }
    Type* newArray = new Type[newCap];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Capacity && i < newCap; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    delete[] array;
    array = newArray;
    Capacity = newCap;
}
```

I don't suppose I can talk you into using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), can I? If not, you really need to know about [The Rule of Three (and friends)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Really. It's important. Trust me.

Comment: @user4581301I tried running this and I'm getting a C3892 error, "'newCap': you cannot assign to a variable that is const". And I want to use std::vectors but I'm trying to teach myself how vectors work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that bit of idiocy out for me. Teach me to not run an example through a compiler. Fixed.

Comment: @useruser4581301 it does run for me now. However, I'm getting a weird error where my array become {memory location, 2, 3, 4, 5}. It may be something else on with the rest of my code however.

Comment: That memory location could just be random garbage. Make sure you don't have a `for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)` or similar off-by-one bug hiding somewhere leaving a value uninitialized. Step through the code with a debugger and see if you can spot where the weird number comes from. The debugger is the programmer's secret weapon.